# Cannot use coxph.predict for type="expected" with newdata in Competing Risks context

Tags: r, predict, survival

I'm using a Cox Proportional Hazards (`survival::coxph`) model in a competing risks context- i.e. multiple event types with one endpoint for each observation. I'm having a hard time using the `coxph.predict` function to show an estimate of expected number of events given a supplied set of covariates and follow-up time.
Here is an example using the mgus2 dataset in the survival package:

```
library(survival)

#Modify data so each subject transitions only once to a state.
crdata <- mgus2
crdata$etime <- pmin(crdata$ptime, crdata$futime)
crdata$event <- ifelse(crdata$pstat==1, 1, 2*crdata$death)
crdata$event <- factor(crdata$event, 0:2, c("censor", "PCM", "death"))

cfit <- coxph(Surv(etime, event) ~ I(age/10) + sex + mspike,
              id = id, crdata)
```

Once I fit a model, and create a "newdata" data frame, R throws an error.

I tried using a from-scratch dataframe but this results in an error suggesting that the column size or the number of rows does not mesh:

```
#providing both follow-up time and covariates
nd=data.frame(etime=81 ,sex= "M", age=60, mspike=1.2)
predict(cfit, newdata=nd ,type="expected")

> Data is not the same size as it was in the original fit
```

I get the same issue Using model.frame when extracting the same data.frame used fitting the model.

```
nd=model.frame(cfit)
predict(cfit,newdata=nd,type="expected")

> Data is not the same size as it was in the original fit
```

This results in the same error. Trying to use the original data frame to make predictions doesn't work either:

```
nd=crdata[1,]
predict(cfit,newdata=nd,type="expected")

> Data is not the same size as it was in the original fit
```

I'm wondering what I'm missing here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's counter-intuitive, but you need to add events to your prediction data frame. These will be ignored in the output.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks for the response! Based on your advice, I tried 

    `nd=data.frame(etime=81, event =factor("PCM"),sex= "M", age=60, mspike=1.2)

predict(cfit,newdata=nd,type="expected")`

But it returned the same error. I don't suppose you might be able to give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my survival package from 2.7 to 3.1 and the error thrown states that "expected" predict type is not available for multistate coxph.

```
> predict(fit,type="expected",newdata=newdat)
Error in predict.coxphms(fit, type = "expected", newdata = newdat) : 
  predict method not yet available for multistate coxph
```